# Java Applet & SSL/Certificate

Tags: java, ssl, applet, certificate

My website uses SSL and takes them directly to a Java applet after login.  The applet yields a warning screen proclaiming that the website's certificate can't be verified.  After clicking "Yes" to continue anyway, a second pop up appears with:

> Identification required.  Please select certificate to be used for authentication.

Underneath that message, there is a white box that I assume is supposed to list certificate options.  Mine doesn't have any options, so I am forced to click "OK" and the applet doesn't load.

The certificates for the website are installed on the browser.  I also installed them by right-clicking on the Java icon within the Windows task bar, clicking "Open Control Panel" and installing them through the Security options.

Nothing seems to work.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have your Tomcat or whatever configured to request or require SSL client certificates. The effect at the client is the same for both: an incoming CertificateRequest. So it pops up the 2nd dialog. If you cancel and it is 'request' not 'require', the applet should load.

I have had numerous problems with applets and HTTPS recently, including what look like Java plugin bugs, and have concluded that the answer is really to load them via HTTP in plaintext.

The first dialog should be fixed by not using a self-signed SSL certificate.

Comment: EJP, I am using Tomcat.  When you refer to "request" over "require", are you talking about the clientAuth attribute in the server.xml file?

Comment: I figured out the issue - it actually had nothing to do with SSL.  It had to do with a missing jar file that the code distributor forgot to provide.  Thanks for your response, EJP.